# How to remove a prefix from the archive names for all subprojects?

Tags: java, gradle

In my multiproject project I'm giving different names to my projects than the folder name. This is the contents of my *settings.gradle* file:

```
include 'eventos', 'modelo', 'negocio', 'negocio-impl', 'persistencia', 'persistencia-impl', 'visao'

rootProject.children.each {it.name = "eventos-" + it.name}
```

This is working well, but I noticed that the generated archives (ear, war, jar) are being named *'eventos-eventos.ear'*, *'eventos-visao.war'*, *'eventos-persistencia.jar'* etc. I don't want this. I would like to strip the prefix 'eventos-' from all this archives as was the case when the project names were the same as the folder names. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

P.S.: Cross-posted: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-remove-a-prefix-from-the-archive-names-for-all-subprojects/12918